# SQL force a row with 0 across the board if no data is available

Tags: sql, sql-server

This question is based on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373243/sql-how-to-force-to-display-row-with-0-if-no-data-available); however, the situation here is different.

In my previous question, I needed to force displaying 0 for any rows that do not have counts. Cross joining and left joining worked wonders for me, and I used it on multiple occasions.

However, in previous case, there was some initial data to join on (e.g., 3 out of 24 rows existed).

In my current case, the query is returning a single row.

```
SELECT ID, StartDate, EndDate, Year, Counts1, Counts2, etc
WHERE data between @startdate and @enddate
```

If it has data within selected range - good, if not - no data is returned. And this is where I have a problem. If there is no data, there is nothing I can join on. So I doubt my previous method would be of any use here.

I also tried coalesce during inserting into table variable

```
INSERT INTO @table SELECT ID, StartDate, EndDate, Year, COALESCE(Counts1, 0) as Counts1, etc
WHERE data between @startdate and @enddate
```

Last resort I came up with is 'union with where not exists', but so far I did not come up with results.

Can anyone please tip me how to proceed with such situation? My desired output if row does not exist is

```
|id   |Start Date   |End Date   |Year   |   Counts1|   Counts2|...
|Text |@startdateval|@enddateval|yearval|      0   |     0    |...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation . . . if you always want one row:

```
SELECT max(ID) as id, @startdate as startdate, @enddate as enddate,
       max(Year) as year, coalesce(max(Counts1), 0) as counts1, coalesce(max(Counts2), 0), etc
. . .
WHERE data between @startdate and @enddate;
```

This will not do what you expect if your original query returns more than 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use a recursive CTE to create a dummy table of all days in a date range, then left join that to your table:

```
declare @startDate date = '2017-10-01'
,@endDate date = '2017-10-31'
;with d as(
SELECT @startDate SD
UNION ALL
SELECT dateadd(day,1,SD)
FROM d
WHERE SD < @endDate
)
```